# Exiting from search menu Ubuntu 20.04 via super key not working

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gui

On Ubuntu 20.04, the search menu does not escape by hitting super key second time. Going into the search menu by super key works fine.

Keyboard and window manager are both disabled, can't exit through super key, as normally. Any ideas about the cause the problem and how to fix this?
[This is the mode I can't exit, clicking on top-left X close doesn't help it only closes the foreground app but not search menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsGyE.jpg)

Comment: Hmmm. My keyboard is not disabled when I do it. Is there a secret or trick to duplicating the problem on other equipment?

Comment: I don't know how you can reproduce it, but I have added an image that might help.

Comment: This happens when I install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel and activate it.

Comment: So you know the cause of the issue: it is the extension changing the behavior. You can still use Esc to quit the overview?

Comment: No Esc does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue. The problem is fixed once I updated the dash-to-panel extension.

- GNOME Shell 3.36.4
- Dash-to-panel 38

Comment: There is no Das-to-panel -v 38.

Comment: You can use firefox browser to visit https://extensions.gnome.org/. There you can get it.

Comment: Fixed after cloning repo from https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel and installing it.